# python bot server does not receive bash messages - missing concept

Tags: python, bots

I have created a Telegram bot using BotFather, https://t.me/botfather

In a Raspberry server, I have some python code answering messages written to bot.

It uses "pyTelegramBotAPI" and is based on this code
https://www.flopy.es/crea-un-bot-de-telegram-para-tu-raspberry-ordenale-cosas-y-habla-con-ella-a-distancia/

Basically it does "bot.polling()"

It works perfect when I write messages into the bot using the smartphone Telegram APP.

The problem is when I write messages into the bot from another computer,
using "bash" + "curl" + "POST"

The server does not receive the bash message, so it does not answer it.

Can someone provide some light on any concept I am missing ?

PD.- the bash+curl code is this one

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="1436067683:ABGcHbGWS3ek1UdKvyRWC7Xtuv1DuyvT6A4"
ID="304688070"
MENSAJE="La Raspberry te saluda."
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage"

curl -s -X POST ${URL} -d chat_id=${ID} -d text="${MENSAJE}"
```

PD #2 .- now I use "json" and have reached an interesting situation :

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"chat_id":"${ID}", "text":"${MENSAJE}"}' ${URL_sndmsg}
```

... produces ...

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}
```

... but I did not change ID neither TOKEN ... and old code still finds the chat ...

Strange

Comment: can you show us an example of how you're sending the message with curl?

Comment: of course - included in main

Comment: update: verify the chat id, if your bot is doing getUpdates (long polling as you describe), send it a message using the app, then check the message.chat.id value of that message.

Comment: chat.id is perfect, hardcoded, no mistake possible, and also verified, both manually and also using "http://telegram.me/myidbot"

Answer (score 0):

the sendMessage endpoint of the bot API is a POST endpoint, and according to [the documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), you need to use JSON data to communicate with it.

the request you made in the question would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="1436067683:ABGcHbGWS3ek1UdKvyRWC7Xtuv1DuyvT6A4"
ID="304688070"
MENSAJE="La Raspberry te saluda."
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot${TOKEN}/sendMessage"

curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"chat_id":"${ID}", "text":"${MENSAJE}"}' ${URL}
```

I'd recommend that you don't use the `-s` option while making tests, that way you can see the output and you could've figure it out.

Comment: I guess you mean "-v" flag, for "verbose", since "-s" is "silent", as far as I know

Comment: I meant what I said, verbose will give you information about curl internal management of the request, but silent will hide the server response.

Comment: sorry, didn't see the "don't use" part

Comment: well, Pablo, as my json does not be accepted, I have read more doc and it says

Comment: We support GET and POST HTTP methods. We support four ways of passing parameters in Bot API requests:

    URL query string
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    application/json (except for uploading files)
    multipart/form-data (use to upload files)